# Selecting a specific div among similar div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for guidance on the following scenario:

**Context:** A page displays a dynamically generated list with X (changes based on the user) number of items, each formatted as follows:

```
<div class="dashboard_section_item">
    <div id="openModal_55872761" class="modalEdit">
        <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="closemodalEdit">X</a>
            <h3>Properties</h3>
        </div>
    </div> <a href="#openModal_55872761">Edit</a>

    <label for="add_listname_label">Assign to list</label>
    <br/>
    <select name="mod_list" class="mod_list">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_uid" class="prod_uid" value=”55872761">
    </div>
```

**1st issue:** Need to show a modal div on top of a product div when the user clicks on a specific item Edit link.

**Current code:**  It seems I have to specify a unique ID for each modal so it knows which item it is associated with. What I have done(see above) is add the item uid to the id and href tags when the list is generated so it’s mapped accordingly for each item which works fine.

**Is there a better way to to this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you, something like this should do:

```
<div id="openModal_55872761" class="modalEdit">
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="closemodalEdit">X</a>
        <h3>Properties</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="someClass" href="#openModal_55872761">Edit</a>

$(document).on('click', 'a.someClass', function() {
    $(this).prev('.modalEdit').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks isherwood. I have just tried your suggestion. It should work fine however I'm having an issue with $this: I have changed it to $this.next since my properties div position on the page has changed and comes right after the edit link but I get the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal' so I assume it's not finding the proper div class item. Any idea?

Comment: I was guessing at the method you're using to invoke the modal since you didn't provide any related code. That may not be correct. My answer was specifically about DOM traversal between the link and the element intended to be modal.

Comment: To invoke the modal I have been using pure CSS actually with pointer-events and playing with the div opacity and transition. I'm going to look more into DOM traversal. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. Then you'd just remove that method call.